# How do I create a Gtk Iconview with a custom CellRendererText

Tags: python, gtk3, gio

I'm investigating how to create in Python (2.7 or above) a GtkIconView that has a custom CellRendererText for the text element of the IconView.

The reason for this, is that I need to override certain properties during the iconview creation.

Looking around I found this example for PyGtk for TreeViews - similar but I need an Introspection example for an IconView

- [Set cellrenderertext foreground color when a row is highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629386/gtk-set-cellrenderertext-foreground-color-when-a-row-is-highlighted)

I've looked at the C++ documentation but I dont really understand how to assign a cellrenderertext to the IconView.

- http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconView.html

Again I've found some python documentation to create a custom cellrenderer for a treeview

- http://www.scribd.com/doc/99516129/41/CellRendererText

Can anyone point me in the correct direction how to modify the example for an IconView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gtk.IconView` inherits from `Gtk.CellLayout`, so you can use the cell layout functions to replace the current text renderer. Something in the vein of:

```
renderers = iconview.get_cells()
iconview.clear()
for r in renderers:
    if not isinstance(r, Gtk.TextRenderer):
        iconview.pack_start(r)
    else:
        iconview.pack_start(my_custom_renderer)
```

I don't know if this works, but that's how I'd go about it.

Answer (score 2):

The official way to go is to use `set_cell_data_func`.

However in the context of an IconView it is done differently to the TreeView case (where you simply pass the custom rendering function to a TreeViewColumn instance).

This had me confused too until I found [this nugget](https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/blob/master/gtk3/sample/gtk-demo/iconview_edit.rb) in the GTK3 Ruby bindings where Kouhei Sutou demonstrates the use of the GtkCellLayout interface to set up cell renderers in an IconView.

**NOTE**: If you previously had setup your columns using setters such as `iconView.text_column = TEXT_IDX`, then you should remove them once your custom renderer is in place or you will see duplicate text labels.