# Python: Changing the select colour in a GtkTreeview

Tags: gtk3, pygtk, gtktreeview

I want to disable the selection colour at a treeview. So I want to set the selected color to white with [modify_base](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.modify_base). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099244/changing-the-selected-item-colour-in-a-gtktreeview-using-python) solution, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
import gi
from gi.repository import Gdk, Gtk
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

treestore = InterfaceTreeStore()
treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
treeview.set_model(treestore)

treeview.modify_base(Gtk.StateFlags.SELECTED, Gdk.Color(red=65535, blue=65535, green=65535))
```

Comment: *pygtk* is gtk 2, *gtk3* tag is for gtk 3. Which version do you use?

Comment: I use Gtk from PyGObject. So Gtk3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gtk_widget_modify_base`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.modify_base) has been deprecated since 3.0. You could have used `gtk_widget_override_background_color`, if it wasn't deprecated since 3.16. It's [documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.override_background_color) states that:

> If you wish to change the way a widget renders its background you should use a custom CSS style

However, if you want to *disable* selection color, the simpliest way is to unselect.

Your `"changed"` signal callback might look something like this:

```
def changed_cb(selection):
    model, iter = get_selected (selection)
    # if there is no selection, iter is None
    if iter is None:
        return
    # do something useful
    # now unselect
    path = model.get_path(iter)
    selection.unselect_path(path)
    path.free() # not sure if python frees it automatically
```